# Chrome page crash when running selenium and capybara under tmux

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, crash, capybara, tmux

I'm using cucumber + selenium + capybara to do test on OSX 10.9.

`chromedriver` is installed via `brew` with latest version 2.10.

When I run the test, the page in chrome which is lunched by selenium is just crashed.  Below are the output in the console :

```
unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
      from tab crashed
        (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.120)
        (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.4 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

If I tried to use the selenium launched chrome, every tab will be crashed.

I googled the problem, the chrome crash issue happened before and fixed after chromedriver 2.6.  As you can see all my chromedriver (2.10) and chrome are the latest ones.

If I switch my selenium driver browser to firefox, it works well.

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: Per the release notes, chromedriver 2.10 is supports Chrome versions 33-36. Not sure if this is causing the problem. [Chromedriver 2.10 notes](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/notes.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.This puzzled me for a long time.

By a happy chance,I run testing in terminal,everything is ok.

The problem only happens when I run testing with tmux session!

[Fix problem for me .](http://borkweb.com/story/chromedriver-doesnt-run-in-tmux)